# Mobius transformation fixing points $z=1,z=-1$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, mobius-transformation

> Let $\varphi$ be a mobius transformation s.t $\varphi(1)=1,\varphi(-1)=-1$. Denote $i\mathbb{R}=C$. What is $\varphi(C)$?

My attempt:
Let $\varphi(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$. Since $\varphi(1)=1,\varphi(-1)=-1$ we have that $\varphi(z)=\frac{az+b}{bz+a}$. I looked at $\varphi(i),\varphi(-i)$ and $\varphi(0)$ and tried to determine under which conditions on $a,b$ they are linearly dependent (meaning they're on the same line) or otherwise when the aren't linearly dependent (and therefore are on the same circle), but I didn't get too far.

Any help would be apprecited.

Comment: In the hope an [animation loop](https://mathcs.holycross.edu/~ahwang/epix/images/gallery-1.2/anim/stereo_proj.gif) is worth a thousand words....

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I'm not sure I'm following.

Comment: I ought to have asked: Have you seen the Riemann sphere and stereographic projection? (If so, rotations of the sphere induce Moebius transformations of the plane, and the rotations shown fix $\pm1$.)

Comment: There are many möbius transformations with these two fixed points. But $\varphi(C) $ is a line or a circle through these two points.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I see it now. I know that in the Riemann sphere the imaginary axis is the intersection of the sphere with $a=0$. But how can I formalize what $\varphi(C)$ is?

Comment: @Jochen Not "through these two points"; the two fixed points are the images of $\pm1$, not of points on the imaginary axis $C$.

Comment: $\pm 1$ are symmetric wrt $C$, therefore $\phi(\pm 1)$ are symmetric wrt $\phi(C)$. So either $\phi(C) = C$ or $\phi(C)$ is a circle with center $x \in \mathbb R$ and radius $r > 0$ s.t. $x^2 - 1 = r^2$ (and any $x, r$ satisfying those conditions are possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $w=\frac{az+b}{bz+a}$ and rearrange to get $z=\frac{b-aw}{wb-a}$.

Now put $w=u+iv$ and do some algebra to find the real part of $z$ in terms of $u$ and $v$.
$$z=\frac{b-au-aiv}{b-ua+ibv}\times\frac{bu-a-ibv}{bu-a-ibv}$$
$$=\frac{b^2u-ab-ib^2v-abu^2+a^2u+iabuv-iabuv+a^2iv-abv^2}{(bu-a)^2+b^2v}$$
So the real part is
$$\frac{b^2u-ab-abu^2+a^2u-abv^2}{(bu-a)^2+b^2v}$$

Since you want the image of the imaginary axis, set this to zero and you get the equation of a circle $$u^2+v^2-u\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab}+1=0$$

Comment: So I need only care about the cases when $ab=0$ and $ab\neq0$?

Comment: Yes, and also $a=b$ is a special case

Comment: But don't we require from a mobius transformation to satisfy $ac-bd\neq0$? Meaning in this case that $a\neq\pm b$. Also. if you could maybe walk me through how you got to this real part because I wasn't able to

Comment: See my amended answer. Also, yes, $a\neq\pm b$

Answer (score 2):

The mapping $\varphi$ with $\varphi(1)=1,\varphi(-1)=-1$ and $\varphi(\infty)=\alpha\neq \pm 1$ is similarly solved as $$\varphi(z)=\frac{\alpha z+1}{z+\alpha}.$$
Then $\varphi(C)$ is the circle (or line) through the three points $$\varphi(0)=\frac 1{\alpha},\varphi(i)=\frac{\alpha i+1}{i+\alpha},\varphi(\infty)=\alpha.$$ It follows that $\varphi(C)$ is the circle (or line) through $\frac 1{\alpha},\frac{\alpha i +1}{i+\alpha}$ and $\alpha$.

**Remark**. It can be checked directly that $\varphi(C)$ is the $y$-axis if and only if $\alpha$ is purely imaginary. Note that if $\alpha$ is real, then $\varphi(i)$ lies on the unit circle.

Comment: What happens if it's neither?

Comment: It will be in general a circle with equation given by the other answer. Or you can just solve it from the three points.